# Difference of Do while/Do until in VBscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

What is the difference between **Do while** and **Do until** loops in **vbscript**, and what are the equivalent loops statements in **javascript** ?

Comment: On Googling "Difference between Do while/Do until in VBscript" it provides me - 
About 102,000 results (0.21 seconds) . Is that not easy ?? basic thing is not to humiliate you but just telling to put some efforts so that u can enhance your learning process

Comment: 1. http://qtp.blogspot.in/2007/05/vbscript-looping-statements.html    2. http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091103210224AAVe7Yl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only difference between `do while` and `do until` is that the first one loops as long as the condition is true, while the second one loops as long as the condition is false.

In Javascript you use `do {} while()` or `while() {}`. Example:

```
var cnt = 0;
do {
  cnt++;
} while (cnt < 10);
```

and:

```
var cnt = 0;
while (cnt < 10) {
  cnt++;
}
```

Use the `!` operator to negate the condition to get the same functionality as `until`.

Comment: The other big difference between the code that you have posted is where the condition is evaluated - that can make a significant difference. In a complex example a `do .. while' will always execute at least once, even if the completion condition is already met, while in a `while` loop the  code loop may not execute at all.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: Yes, thanks for the clarification. Note that it's the same difference as between `do while ... loop` and `do ... loop while` in VBScript (and the corresponding for `until`).

Answer (score 2):

Do while, (Repeat Code While a Condition is True)

```
Do While i>10
  some code
Loop
```

or

```
Do
  some code
Loop While i>10
```

Do until, (Repeat Code Until a Condition Becomes True)

```
Do Until i=10
  some code
Loop
```

or

```
Do
  some code
Loop Until i=10
```

javascripts,

```
while ( i>10)
{
   some code
}
```

or,

```
do
{
   some code
} while (i>10);
```

Hope you got the idea

Comment: Your loop examples are not equivalent. `Until i=10` has a different semantic than `While i>10` (`Until i <=10` would be equivalent to the latter). Also there's a significant difference between post-test loops (code block will execute at least once) and pre-test loops (code block may be skipped over entirely).

Answer (score 1):

[Google is your friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eked04a7.aspx). The `do-while` loop executes **1 or more** times, while a `while` loop executes **0 or more** times.

From MSDN:

```
While   Required unless Until is used. Repeat the loop until condition is False.
Until   Required unless While is used. Repeat the loop until condition is True.
```

Comment: The question was about the difference between `Do While` and `Do Until`, not about the difference between pre-test and post-test loops. In VBScript the `Do-Loop` structure can be implemented as pre-test or post-test with either `While` or `Until` condition.